# Inconsistency detected by ld.so: elf_get_dynamic_info: Assertion `info[DT_RUNPATH] == NULL' failed! trying to run qemu using glibc-2.33

Tags: 18.04, compiling, c++, libraries, glibc

For educational pourpoise I would like to run the latest version of qemu using glibc-2.33,instead of glibc installed as default on the 18.04. The final goal is to virtualize windows 10 arm64 on the jetson nano where I have installed ubuntu 18.04. So this is what I did :

```
wget https://launchpad.net/glibc/head/2.33/+download/glibc-2.33.tar.gz

tar -xf glibc-2.33.tar.gz    

mkdir build-glibc-2.33

cd build-glibc-2.33

/root/Scrivania/Work/I9/win10arm/glibc-2.33/./configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.33

SYSROOT=/opt/glibc-2.33

LDFLAGS="-L${SYSROOT}/lib -Wl,-rpath=${SYSROOT}/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker=${SYSROOT}/lib/ld-2.33.so" CFLAGS="-I${SYSROOT}/include --sysroot=${SYSROOT}" make

LDFLAGS="-L${SYSROOT}/lib -Wl,-rpath=${SYSROOT}/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker=${SYSROOT}/lib/ld-2.33.so" CFLAGS="-I${SYSROOT}/include --sysroot=${SYSROOT}" make install
    
GLIBC=/root/Scrivania/Work/I9/win10arm/build-glibc-2.33

GCONV_PATH=${GLIBC}/iconvdata LC_ALL=C     \
${GLIBC}/elf/ld.so --library-path \
${GLIBC}:\
${GLIBC}/math:\
${GLIBC}/elf:\
${GLIBC}/dlfcn:\
${GLIBC}/nss:\
${GLIBC}/nis:\
${GLIBC}/rt:\
${GLIBC}/resolv:\
${GLIBC}/crypt:\
${GLIBC}/nptl:\
#${GLIBC}/dfp \

/root/Scrivania/Work/I9/win10arm/qemu/build/aarch64-softmmu/./qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt-2.12 -enable-kvm -cpu host -smp 2 -m 2048 -device qemu-xhci -device usb-kbd -device usb-mouse -drive file=/root/Scrivania/Work/isoarm/win10arm.qcow2,if=virtio -nic user,model=virtio -device usb-storage,drive=install -device usb-storage,drive=drivers -drive file="$isoname1",if=none,id=install,media=cdrom,readonly=on -drive file="$virtio",if=none,media=cdrom,readonly=on,id=drivers -bios /root/Scrivania/Work/I9/win10arm/QEMU_EFI.fd -device ramfb
```

but the error is :

```
**Inconsistency detected by ld.so: get-dynamic-info.h: 141: elf_get_dynamic_info: Assertion `info[DT_RUNPATH] == NULL' failed!**
```

but anyway qemu runs correctly. I don't know if it runs despite the error or not.

Comment: Try `--enable-new-dtags` in linker flags: `LDFLAGS="-L${SYSROOT}/lib -Wl,-rpath=${SYSROOT}/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker=${SYSROOT}/lib/ld-2.33.so -Wl,--enable-new-dtags`

Comment: like this ? LDFLAGS="-L${SYSROOT}/lib -Wl,-rpath=${SYSROOT}/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker=${SYSROOT}/lib/ld-2.33.so -Wl,--enable-new-dtags" make -j4
AND : LDFLAGS="-L${SYSROOT}/lib -Wl,-rpath=${SYSROOT}/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker=${SYSROOT}/lib/ld-2.33.so -Wl,--enable-new-dtags" make install ? : I get the same error as before.

Answer (score 2):

I installed `glibc` using `homebrew` and came across the issue:

```
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: get-dynamic-info.h: 143: elf_get_dynamic_info: Assertion `info[DT_RPATH] == NULL' failed!
```

That was similar to yours, and I referred to the link:
[Homebrew/discussions: Difficulties installing Homebrew `glibc` on Centos 7 - GitHub.](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/2011)

Finally, I used command `patchelf --remove-rpath /my/libdir/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` to handle it. `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` is the symbolic link to `ld.so`. May this can help you.

Comment: On what version of Ubuntu do you run homebrew ?

Comment: @SorenA I ran homebrew on Centos7, and I updated the `glibc` from version `2.17` to `2.23`. Kernel: `Linux 3.10.0-1127.13.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`, OS: `CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)`.

Comment: Centos is not Ubutu andtherefor offtopic here.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I haven't tried it on Ubuntu, but it may work as well. It's only a suggestion for solving the problem, you can still have a try.

Comment: This is the only answer I found related and works for me, though the original GitHub issue is also helpful. Incase you encounter `patchelf: open: Permission denied`, you can make a copy of both `~/.linuxbrew/Cellar/glibc/2.23/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` and `~.linuxbrew/Cellar/glibc/2.23/lib/ld-2.23.so` and then run `chmod +w ~.linuxbrew/Cellar/glibc/2.23/lib/ld-2.23.so`. Run `patchily` again and it should allow you to run `brew postinstall glibc`.

Comment: Sorry it should be `~/.linuxbrew` in my comment above.

Comment: And also run `chmod +w ~/.linuxbrew/Cellar/glibc/2.23/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, then patchelf should work.